# How to run VBA in excel, when Excel filename got changed

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a Workbook (1) contains 2 sheets. In my program, I would like to generate a workbook (2) which Create 2 sheets. Then the program will filter the table and copy values from workbook 1 to workbook 2.

But my problem is my workbook (1) name will get changed every time. I tried to use `ActiveWorkbook.Name`. But when the program is running, it will create a new workbook then suddenly it became an active workbook.

I named my main Workbook (1) as Filevalue. But not working. How to solve this problem. I need to run this program eventhough when the name get changed. Help me

```
Sub createlandDE()

Filepath = ActiveWorkbook.path
FileValue = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Problem With Activeworkbook
NameValue = Format(Date, "yymmdd") & "-DE"
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.add
Dim path As String
Dim FSO As Object
path = Filepath & "\" & NameValue & ".xlsx"
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FSO.FileExists(path) Then
    On Error Resume Next
        Workbooks(NameValue & ".xlsx").Close False
        Kill path
        wb.SaveAs path
        Sheets(3).Delete
    Else
    wb.SaveAs path
    Sheets(3).Delete
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws, ws1, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim table1, table2 As ListObject
Dim rng1 As Range

Sheets(1).Name = "Main view"
Sheets(2).Name = "Overall view"
Set ws1 = Workbooks(NameValue & ".xlsx").Worksheets("Main view")

ws1.ListObjects.add(xlSrcRange, ws1.Range("A$1:$J$1"), , xlYes).Name = "MainTable"
Set table1 = ws1.ListObjects(1)

Set ws = Workbooks(FileValue).Worksheets("Main") 'Problem With Activeworkbook
ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Dealer Country Code").CurrentPage = "DE"

With ws
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Range(.Range("A4"), .Range("J" & LastRow))
End With

rng1.Copy

ws1.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Set ws2 = Sheets("Overall view")

ws2.ListObjects.add(xlSrcRange, ws2.Range("A$1:$Q$1"), , xlYes).Name = "OverallTable"
Set table2 = ws2.ListObjects(1)
Worksheets("Overall view").ListObjects("OverallTable").TableStyle = "Table Style 1"

Workbooks(FileValue).Activate 'Problem With Activeworkbook
Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1
Sheet2.ListObjects("DataTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=12
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: If you write the code correctly, you will never have to rely on which workbook is active. Always fully qualify your Ranges and Worksheets.

Comment: The wb you run the code from can be considered, `thisworkbook` so then you can dim the workbook you are starting from
`dim bk:set bk=thisworkbook`

Comment: Just replace all your `Workbooks(NameValue & ".xlsx")` by `ThisWorkbook`, [@ScottCraner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) is right